# Having a rough time decided on FLOAT, DOUBLE, or DECIMAL

Tags: mysql

Currently using MySQL version 5.1.6

This is my first real world build and so far I have actually been enjoying it; however, I now am stuck on a decision regarding a field datatype and hoping someone could sort it out for me.

I essentially have 10 fields that are all different test results. The numbers range from -100 to 100 and can have a decimal with one spot after the actual point.

For example, -5.1, 0, 1, 16.3, 99.2, and 100 are all possible data. From what I have read, one should use DECIMAL for those things that we usually measure and are exact (which these are), whereas FLOAT and DOUBLE are approximations, which I do not really want (though I am sure at this level, the approximation is very small if existent at all).

If I use DECIMAL, do I have to include a space for the '-' at the beginning if used? I.E, would I use DECIMAL(4,1) or DECIMAL(5,1) or am I way off here? I might be overthinking this a bit.

Comment: So your question is really just about how you should choose the dimensional argument to `DECIMAL`? And all that chatter about `FLOAT` and `DECIMAL` is redundant? Then how about just reading [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negative symbol does NOT count as a digit in your calculation, so DECIMAL(4,1) should be fine.

Edit: That also seems like the right field to use for your purposes. Try it out!

Comment: Both of your responses helped me out, but since yours was first I chose it as best. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`DECIMAL(4,1)` will be enough, the sign digit does *not* need to be included.

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

> For example, a `DECIMAL(3,0)` column supports a range of -999 to 999

Decimal will be indeed the best option for your needs. Float and Double can give you ugly numbers (e.g. 0.2 cannot be represented as float, you'd get 0.19999999)